# Bad Request error: 400 in React js using axios put

Tags: javascript

i am working with react js in a dashboard, but when I try to do a PUT request, the response is error 400 or 401, the message is:

```
{"code":"missing_params","message":"Your update call does not have any parameter. At least one parameter is required."}
```

But, I added the params to the request, I do not understand what i'm doing wrong?

```
update() {

    var url="https://icgaid.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets/65"

    axios(url,{method:'put',headers: { 'authorization':'Basic ZHBhbG1hQGljZy5jb20uZ3Q6Z3VhdGU1MDI==','Content-Type':'application/json'},body:{'status':4}})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {console.log(json);this.setState({re:json})})
}
```

Comment: Should the url be `url = https://icgaid.freshdesk.com/api/v2?tickets=65` ? Or some variation of that? But it's weird to be asking for params in a put action.

Comment: no the variation should be the number of id that is in the url, in fact I already solved it, I had to modify the axios method by a fetch.

Answer (score 2):

The object should have a member called data, you have body, also you should check the API documentation, maybe you have a typo, the parameters names could be wrong.